# Transforming Data from One Excel Template to Another Excel Template?

Tags: excel, xslt, transformation

I want to take data from one Excel Template (provided by a client) and then transform it into my own internal Excel Template.

I basically want to be able to write up a transformation (XSLT) that calls out field names from the client's Excel Template, and then imports the values into corresponding fields in my own template through some sort of mapping process.

Is there a way to do this?
For instance, the client may have the following columns:
first name
last name
address
phone number

However,my template may only have
first name
last name
phone number

I'd want the transformation to just automatically pull the values from the three corresponding fields in the client's Excel template.

Is this possible? If so, what kind of process flow am I looking at?

Note: By Excel template I just mean a well formatted Excel file with fields and cell values.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, here's the process as I see it:

1) Create an XML data and schema file from your Excel spreadsheet.  See [this reference.](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/create-an-xml-data-file-and-xml-schema-file-from-worksheet-data-HA010263509.aspx)

2) Import the XML schema into the client Excel spreadsheet.  See [this reference.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg469857.aspx)

3) Export the client Excel spreadsheet to an XML data file, too.

4) Run a transformation over both documents in a fell swoop, basically:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common">

  <xsl:variable name="mine"   select="document(/path/to/your.xml)"/>
  <xsl:variable name="client" select="document(/path/to/client.xml)"/>

  <xsl:variable name="both">
    <both>
      <xsl:copy-of select="exsl:node-set($mine)/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="exsl:node-set($client)/>
    </both>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="exsl:node-set($both)/whatever>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- More templates here to do what you will with all the data,
       whether it be copying, sorting first, or etc. -->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

5) Import the result back into your Excel document.

That's rather bare, and I have not done this in a while, so some specific steps may have changed across version bumps in Excel since then.  The last step needs to be done outside of the transform since XSLT is non-destructive (does not modify input source documents, but only outputs new result documents.

Also, that uses the XSLT Extension Function exsl:node-set().  Depending on what tools you're using, i.e., IE, you may need to switch it to the MSXSL Extension version.

```
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
```

and

```
msxsl:node-set()
```

respectively.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you. I can't wait to try this!